# Change string comma separator for Woocommerce product category list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to figure out how to change the comma separator that shows in-between product category taxonomies on the front end single product view.

If I had three categories (1 2 3) for Product A then on the single product page displays the meta as - *Categories: 1, 2, 3*

I would like to change the separator comma displayed in-between the categories. For example to |
which would then display the meta as *Categories: 1 | 2 | 3*

I came across this code while searching for a way to do this:

```
// Content Views Pro - modify separator between categories
add_filter( 'pt_cv_post_terms_output', 'cvp_theme_post_terms_modify_separator', 100, 3 );
function cvp_theme_post_terms_modify_separator( $args, $links, $taxonomy_terms ) {
    $args = implode( ' / ', $links ); # Remove the slash to use no separator
    return $args;
}
```

I'm hoping I will be able to use something similar to achieve what I mentioned above. PHP knowledge isn't that great so any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something simple.

First you need to understand by yourself how to override WooCommerce templates via your active theme. So read with attention:  [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

So you need to copy the template file [`/single-product/meta.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.0/templates/single-product/meta.php) in your active child theme (or theme) folder under "woocommerce" subfolder >  "single-product" subfolder.

Once done, open / edit this file and replace line **`34`**:

```
<?php echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
```

by the following line:

```
<?php echo wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id(), ' | ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Category:', 'Categories:', count( $product->get_category_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
```

---

**Addition: For product tags** replace line **`36`**:

```
<?php echo wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', count( $product->get_tag_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
```

by the following line:

```
<?php echo wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ' | ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', count( $product->get_tag_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
```

---

Related docs: [Function wc_get_product_category_list](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_product_category_list.html) and [Function wc_get_product_tag_list](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_product_tag_list.html)